# Understanding how to prove a bijection into three sets

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I understand how to prove if there is a bijection from A onto B. However, say that there is a bijection from A onto B and a bijection from B onto C. How would I prove that that there is a bijection from A onto C?

Answer (score 1):

If $f:A \to B$ is a bijection and $g : B \to C$ is a bijection, then $h = g \circ f$ is a bijection from $A$ to $C$.

Now that I've told you what the bijection *is*, can you prove the two necessary properties?

I'll get you started:

Injectivity. To show $h$ injective, we'll assume $h(x) = h(y)$ and will conclude that $x = y$.

Assume $h(x) = h(y)$ for $x, y \in A$. THen

$$
g(f(x)) = g(f(y))
$$
Letting $u = f(x)$ and $v = f(y)$, we have $g(u) = g(v)$. But $g$ is injective, so $u = v$. Thus $f(x) = f(y)$. But $f$ is injective, so ...